# How to I set the default startup window size for an X11 application (such as xmgrace)

Tags: macos, x11, xterm, xmgrace

I've been trying to run through the `.Xresources` method, with no success (see comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm#comment197620_161704)  from a related question)

So what do I need to modify to make sure my Xmgrace window is of a particular size? When I run `xmgrace myplot.agr` it always ends up as a 680x700 window. I would like to set it to something different, as I always end up having to resize and click-scroll (Xmgrace does not like scroll-wheels).

Any thoughts or ideas most welcome.

Comment: Hmm. Xresources are ancient, but should still work. Note that case is important, so if you entered Xmgrace in your Xresources file it won't work.

Comment: What would be the more current way of doing this?

Comment: No idea... Some applications store the last know position of their window and restore that on start. You could try giving the window size directly on the command line: `xmgrace -geometry 1000x1000 myplot.agr`

Comment: This actually works... I've aliased `xmgrace` to `xmgrace -geometry 1050x750` as a workaround and have thus indirectly solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per comments (and source), you could set the size and position of `xmgrace` in your `$HOME/.Xdefaults` file:

```
XMgrace*geometry: 1050x750
```

or (more specific)

```
XMgrace*mainWin.geometry: 1050x750
```

depending on how it uses the `geometry` resource during initialization.

[The FAQ](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/doc/FAQ.html#ss5.7) does not give more than a hint of the available resources, but is pretty clear that the classname is `XMgrace`.  To get a complete list of resources, you'd have to read the [source-code](ftp://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/pub/grace/src/), which (for instance) in `/src/xmgrace.c` has

```
String fallbackResourcesHighRes[] = {
    "XMgrace*mainWin.width: 680",
    "XMgrace*mainWin.height: 700",
    "XMgrace*fontList:-*-helvetica-medium-r-normal-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*-*",
    "XMgrace.consoleDialog*text.fontList:-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-12-*-*-*->
    "XMgrace*HContainer.marginHeight: 3",
    "XMgrace*VContainer.marginHeight: 3",
    NULL
};
```

It decides to use *that* based on the screensize:

```
screen = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
if (HeightOfScreen(screen) < 740) {
    lowres = TRUE;
}
```

and (seeing no command-line arguments in the source) is configurable only using X resources.  The `-geometry` option is a standard [X toolkit option](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/X.7.html#sect6), used by other programs such as xterm.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for